# Does nesting `if`s increase performances?

Tags: performance, optimization, if-statement, conditional-statements, short-circuiting

If I have this code:

```
if (isFoo() && isBar())
{
    ...
}
```

The program will calculate the first condition, then calculate the second condition, then determine whether to go through or skip the block below.

However, if I nest the conditions like so:

```
if (isFoo())
    if(isBar())
    {
        ...
    }
```

Now it checks the first condition, and if it's false it doesn't bother with the second condition.

If the second condition (being a function) is a time-consuming memory-expensive hog it seems to be better to nest it.

Is this true? I've never seen code like this before and I made an assumption after the first example, but IMO it's highly possible.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: This is certainly not "language-agnostic", but most languages short circuit the boolean and the two constructs are identical.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks for your comment, I've re-tagged the question (hope there aren't anymore problems now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#/C++ and many other languages you have two logical `AND` operators actually: `&` and `&&`:

`&` operator will evaluate both conditions

`&&` operator will evaluate only first, and if it equals `FALSE`, than it skips second part of expression.

The same applies for logical `OR` operators too. There are two operator: `|` and `||`:

`|` operator will evaluate both conditions

`||` operator will evaluate only first, and if it equals `TRUE`, than it skips second part of expression.

So, answering your question, in your example you are using `&&`, which will behave as two nested `if`'s

**[EDIT]**: Ok, it is not that easy to find example of using of | and &, personally I have used them in shortest-code contests)) This is where they are really useful (not because they are shorter than && and ||). Also consider following example:

```
static bool LaunchFirstRocket()
{
    // Launching rocket if all is ok return true, or return false if we failed to launch it.
}

static bool LaunchSecondRocket()
{
    // Launching rocket if all is ok return true, or return false if we failed to launch it.
} 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (LaunchFirstRocket() & LaunchSecondRocket())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Both rockets have launched successfully!");
    }
}
```

Here we will force to execute both methods regardless of outcome of first one. If first rocket failed, we still want to launch second one, this is our logic. Yes, there are a **LOT** of other ways to write such code, but this is just an example for **educational purposes**.

Comment: That's really interesting. Is there a way I'd rather use `&` or `|`?

Comment: It is a rare case when you need them, but I have such cases in my experience. I will be adding example to my answer

Comment: Updated, take a look, maybe this is not the best example, but it is just to give an idea.

Comment: It's a great example! I guess the rule of thumb is to use them when the methods have a side-effect you want. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: `&` is a bitwise AND not a logical operator, you would normally use it when AND'ing together two integers.

Comment: @ Christoffer - no, in C# it represents bitwise AND and a logical AND. And those are separate. Result of former is integer, but result of latter is boolean

Answer (score 3):

It depends from programming language.

Most of modern/popular languages support [Short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) which means that program doesn't evaluate the whole expression, but stops evaluation immediately after gets the result of the whole expression (others gave examples already).

## But there are exceptions

Two languages I know which **doesn't support** short circuit evaluation are Microsoft VB(6) and VB.NET.

VB6 doesn't support it at all, so here nesting `If`s if common optimization technique.
Moreover in expressions like

`If Not rs Is Nothing And Not rs.EOF`

not using nesting `If`s gives execution error while `rs` is `Nothing`.

`VB.NET` introduced two new logical operators [`AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [`OrElse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ea1sssb2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) which support short circuit evaluation.

Standard `VB.NET` `And` and `Or` operators doesn't support short circuit evaluation, which is common source of bugs in case of newcomer developers.

## Optimalizations

In both cases (language supports and not short circuit evaluation) you can check 
expressions in order of *quicker to evaluate first*.

So instead of (checking in DB if user is female, with even key and it's logged in):

```
if (db.getUserSex() == FEMALE && userKey % 2 == 0 && userKey % 2 && isUserLogged)
```

use (check if logged in (boolean), with even key (arithmetic operator) and check gender in DB in the end):

```
if (isUserLogged && userKey % 2 == 0 && db.getUserSex() == FEMALE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe most compiler would do this optimization for you. If the first condition of && is false, the second one would not be executed.

Answer (score 1):

> The program will calculate the first condition, then calculate the second condition,

No, not in most modern languages (for example C, C++). Since it's known that if the first condition is false, then the value of the `AND` expression cannot possibly be anything other than false, so the second part is not evaluated. In these two languages, the standard explicitly defines this optimization (called "short-circuit evaluation").

Comment: There are AND expressions which will not be short-circuited

Comment: @SergeyS See William Pursell's comment.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  As others have noted, in compiled languages with [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) (such as C and C++), both versions will likely compile to exactly the same code.

In some interpreted languages, such as Perl, the second version may, in fact, be *very slightly* slower than the first, because there is a tiny amount of overhead in entering a code block.  For instance, this artificial benchmark shows the difference clearly:

```perl
use Benchmark ':all';
my $count = shift || 10_000_000;
our ($foo, $bar, $baz) = (1, 1, 1);
timethese( $count, {
    'and'    => 'if ($foo && $bar) { $baz++; }',
    'nested' => 'if ($foo) { if ($bar) { $baz++; } }',
});
```

Output:

```
Benchmark: timing 10000000 iterations of and, nested...
       and:  2 wallclock secs ( 2.41 usr +  0.00 sys =  2.41 CPU) @ 4149377.59/s (n=10000000)
    nested:  4 wallclock secs ( 3.54 usr +  0.00 sys =  3.54 CPU) @ 2824858.76/s (n=10000000)
```

In practice, of course, the difference is likely to be completely insignificant, especially compared to the general overhead of using an interpreted language to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

All modern languages will short-circuit any AND'ed clauses.  So, in your example, if isFoo() was false, it wouldn't even bother checking isBar(), and it would exit the if statement.

Comment: Not any AND'ed clauses. There AND'ed clauses which will not be short-circuited.